# Show the difference between a given commit ID and the commit just one before

Tags: git

I like to search my git log with

```
git log --all --grep='foobar'
```

This gives us i.a. the ID of the commit. And now I would like to see the differences between the just found commit and one before the commit without checking out to the old commit. Is this possible?

Wishcode:`git diff ID ID-1`

Comment: [git diff <commit> <commit>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit> (from the docs).

Comment: @benvc My problem is, that I don't know the commit ID of the second commit. I search my log, what gives me only the ID of the found commit.

Comment: The parent of a commit is `hash^1` or `hash~1`; the digit can be omitted. However, it's even easier: `git show <hash>` means `git log --no-walk hash; git diff hash^ hash`, more or less. Note that `git show` produces *combined diffs* for merge commits (commits with more than one parent).

Comment: @torek super thanks :) works great! with `hash~X` you can diff X steps back

Comment: [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Comment: Yes, `~<number>` moves back that many first-parents. Note that this is a *commit graph* operation; see the gitrevisions documentation in phd's comment.

Comment: @torek How is this (your first comment) not an actual answer ? :-) (not to call you lazy considering the *ton* of answers you write around here... but now that you said it nobody will just post it as an answer after the facts I guess). Minor thing, anyway, I'll just check metaSE. (edit : [oh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins) ^^)